# some problems to solve in class _init_?

Tags: python, inheritance

```
from tkinter import *
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
            Frame._init_(self,master)
            self.pack()


myapp=App()
myapp.master.title("My Do-Nothing Application")
myapp.master.maxsize(1000, 400)
myapp.mainloop()
```

**Error:**

```
Frame._init_(self,master)
AttributeError: type object 'Frame' has no attribute '_init_'
```

I have writed a simple code,but there's some mistakes,I try my best to solve it,but I can't.Anyone could help me to solve it?Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
            Frame.__init__(self,master)
            self.pack()
```

Like the App's `__init__`, the Frame also needs two undescores either side for its `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `__init__` instead of `_init_`, i.e. with two underscores on each side.